# Highcharts DateTime xAxis and tooltip formatting issue

Tags: highcharts

I have some elapsed times that are not displaying properly in a scatter chart and can't seem to get them to display the way I want. For example I have elapsed times like 00:02:45, 00:00:28 and 00:03:31. On my xAxis the times are being displayed from 04:59:30 to 05:04:00. And the above mentioned times in the tooltip are displayed like "05 hrs 02 mins 45 secs", "05 hrs 00 mins 28 secs" and "05 hrs 03 mins 31 secs".

I don't know why 5 is being added as the hrs when it should be 0. How can I fix this?

```
if (data.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                scores.push({ name: data[i].fname + " " + data[i].lname, x: Date.parse(data[i].elapsedTime), y: data[i].score });
            }

            Highcharts.chart('avgFirstTryChart', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'scatter',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Average Score First Try'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Elapsed Time (hours)'
                    },
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        day: '%H:%M:%S'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value)
                        }
                    },
                    startOnTick: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        enabled: true,
                        text: 'Score'
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    showLastLabel: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    scatter: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 5,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{point.name}, {point.x: %H hrs %M mins %S secs} - [score {point.y}%]'
                        }
                    },
                    series: {
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    var point = this,
                                        series = point.series,
                                        chart = series.chart,
                                        xAxis = series.xAxis;

                                    xAxis.setExtremes(this.x - 25000, this.x + 25000);
                                    chart.showResetZoom();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Score',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data: scores
                }]
            });
        }
```

Comment: Converting the results to seconds and feeding that into highcharts would solve the problem

Comment: Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: I was thinking you could just do; 00:02:45 = 0 * 3600 + 2 * 60 + 45. But it is probably better to use datetime as you have done. So I suggest you add `console.log(Date.parse(data[i].elapsedTime))` to your `for` loop, and then look at the values it returns to figure out what is wrong with them.

Comment: The elapsedTime is being returned like -2208970634230, which I believe is milliseconds. How would you convert to seconds as you suggested?

Comment: For highcharts to use datetime, time needs to be in milliseconds, so that is good. Without being able to see the actual values you input (assuming they are '00:02:45' etc) I would do this: `Date.parse('2017-01-01 ' + data[i].elapsedTime)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that results in NaN. The actual elapsedTimes are like '1900-01-01T00:02:45.77', '1900-01-01T00:00:28.5'...etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155521/discussion-between-ewolden-and-user721126).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles across this, the problem was the values along the x-axis. User had the following:

```
data[0].elapsedTime = '1900-01-01T00:02:45.77'
data[1].elapsedTime = '1900-01-01T00:00:28.50'
```

Which was parsed as:

```
Date.parse(data[0].elapsedTime) = -2208970634230
Date.parse(data[1].elapsedTime) = -2208992371500
```

The simple solution was to remove remove seconds since 1900, like this:

```
Date.parse(data[0].elapsedTime) - Date.parse('1900-01-01T00:00:00.00') = 165770
Date.parse(data[1].elapsedTime) - Date.parse('1900-01-01T00:00:00.00') = 28500
```

That way, the graph shows elapsed time as milliseconds, and since it is formatted to only show HH:MM:SS the year does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable UTC time for axis scaling with `useUTC` property.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.setOptions

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/a6h2k4Lv/